# How to GROUP BY query with one key returning multiple values in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a Users Index with users with the following structure in Elastic Search. We are trying to extract the skill object inside of the skill array.

```
{
  "first_name":"xxxx",
  "last_name":"xxxx",
  "skills":[
  {
     "years_of_experience": 1,
     "id": "1",
     "skill": { 
      "id":"1",
      "label":"java",
      "category":"Coding"
     }
  }, 
  {
     "years_of_experience": 2,
     "id": "2",
     "skill":{ 
      "id":"2",
      "label":"Python",
      "category":"Coding"
     }
  }, 
  {
     "years_of_experience": 1,
     "id": "1",
     "skill": { 
      "id":"3",
      "label":"Wix",
      "category":"CMS"
     }
  }
  ]
}
```

How can I return all the distinct labels with their id and category

I have tried this query:

```
{
  "from":0,
  "size":0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_code": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "skills.skill.label.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but it is only returning the label and docs count:

```
                {
                    "key": "Data Factory",
                    "doc_count": 2
                },
                {
                    "key": "Databricks",
                    "doc_count": 2
                },
                {
                    "key": "Pyspark",
                    "doc_count": 2
                },
                {
                    "key": "AWS",
                    "doc_count": 1
                },
                {
                    "key": "Wix",
                    "doc_count": 1
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to use [nested aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html) along with [terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) and [top hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) aggregation, to achieve your required result.**

Adding a working example with index mapping, data, search query, and search result.

**Index Mapping:**

```
 {
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "skills": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "skill": {
            "type": "nested"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
    {
  "first_name": "xxxx",
  "last_name": "xxxx",
  "skills": [
    {
      "years_of_experience": 1,
      "id": "1",
      "skill": {
        "id": "1",
        "label": "java",
        "category": "Coding"
      }
    },
    {
      "years_of_experience": 2,
      "id": "2",
      "skill": {
        "id": "2",
        "label": "Python",
        "category": "Coding"
      }
    },
    {
      "years_of_experience": 1,
      "id": "1",
      "skill": {
        "id": "3",
        "label": "Wix",
        "category": "CMS"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
   {
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "nested_skills": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "skills.skill"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_code": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "skills.skill.label.keyword",
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "top_skills_hits": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 1,
                "_source": {
                  "includes": [
                    "skills.skill.id",
                    "skills.skill.category"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
 "aggregations": {
    "nested_skills": {
      "doc_count": 3,
      "by_code": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "Python",     // note this
            "doc_count": 1,
            "top_skills_hits": {
              "hits": {
                "total": {
                  "value": 1,
                  "relation": "eq"
                },
                "max_score": 1.0,
                "hits": [
                  {
                    "_index": "65544482",
                    "_type": "_doc",
                    "_id": "1",
                    "_nested": {
                      "field": "skills",
                      "offset": 1,
                      "_nested": {
                        "field": "skill",
                        "offset": 0
                      }
                    },
                    "_score": 1.0,
                    "_source": {
                      "id": "2",                  // note this
                      "category": "Coding"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "Wix",
            "doc_count": 1,
            "top_skills_hits": {
              "hits": {
                "total": {
                  "value": 1,
                  "relation": "eq"
                },
                "max_score": 1.0,
                "hits": [
                  {
                    "_index": "65544482",
                    "_type": "_doc",
                    "_id": "1",
                    "_nested": {
                      "field": "skills",
                      "offset": 2,
                      "_nested": {
                        "field": "skill",
                        "offset": 0
                      }
                    },
                    "_score": 1.0,
                    "_source": {
                      "id": "3",
                      "category": "CMS"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "java",
            "doc_count": 1,
            "top_skills_hits": {
              "hits": {
                "total": {
                  "value": 1,
                  "relation": "eq"
                },
                "max_score": 1.0,
                "hits": [
                  {
                    "_index": "65544482",
                    "_type": "_doc",
                    "_id": "1",
                    "_nested": {
                      "field": "skills",
                      "offset": 0,
                      "_nested": {
                        "field": "skill",
                        "offset": 0
                      }
                    },
                    "_score": 1.0,
                    "_source": {
                      "id": "1",
                      "category": "Coding"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: @Justin did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Comment: Hey ESCoder, i just went through, I realise i have made a mistake in the data structure. Do you think you can help please?

Comment: @Justin Sure :) Let me update my answer, with your new data structure

Comment: @Justin please go through my updated answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: I am getting this error when puttng the mapping: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [mappings : {properties={skills={type=nested, properties={skill={type=nested}}}}}]

Comment: @Justin which version of elasticsearch are you using? If you are using ES version below 7, then you need to add the type name in the index mapping defintion.

Comment: We are using 7.10

Comment: @Justin I have also used ES 7.8 and tested the above query locally also. Can you please share the exact index mapping definition that you are using ? Because the error that you are getting, indicates that there is some issue with the parameters used in the index mapping definition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226781/discussion-between-justin-and-escoder).